# How can I force Xcode/xcodebuild to run an old project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, xcodebuild

I've written a bash script to go through all the svn commits in a date range, check them out, build and attach instruments, and take a screenshot on the simulator. (The goal is to make a little film about our iterative design process and how the app has changed over time.)

However, these old checkins have *all sorts* of build errors, analyzer errors and other ancient weirdness. (Apparently we've improved over time.)

I realize that this goes against everything we'd normally want as developers, but in this special case...

**Is there a way to get xcodebuild to just plow through and launch whatever monstrosity results from a build?** I don't really care if it is crashy or trying to link against something which was mistakenly not included in a project. I just want a screenshot of the main UI.

The build command I'm using so far is:

```
 xcodebuild -target ${BUILDTARGETNAME} -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator${IOSSIMULATORSDK} -arch i386 TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=${TARGETEDDEVICEFAMILY} RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=0 GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0 clean build
```

Is there anything else I can do to encourage/force the build to continue through anything that might go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore warnings, but not build errors. To ignore some warnings you need to change xcode build settings in Warnings sections

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be [downloading an old version of Xcode (4.5.2, in my case) here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode). The old versions are less picky about things like retain cycles and pointer incompatibility.

That in addition to `RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=0 GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0` made things finally build.